# SplashScreen is not working in android studio

Tags: android, splash-screen

I am using android studio 2.2.3. I included a splash screen in my program.but it is not working. Splash screen activity does not showing .it directly enter in to the homepage.`
**Manifest file**

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".SplashScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
</application>
```

`

**SplashScreen activity**

```
import android.content.Intent;

import android.os.Handler;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class SplashScreen extends AppCompatActivity {

private final int SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH = 3000;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
            /* Create an Intent that will start the Menu-Activity. */
            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,MainActivity.class);
            SplashScreen.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            SplashScreen.this.finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_DISPLAY_LENGTH);
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

change main activity to default

Comment: can't run while adding this.it shows "default activity not found"

Comment: <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" />
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

Answer (score 2):

I know this was posted a while ago, but there was never a true answer!

What you need to do is NOT just remove:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

But to cut them, and MOVE them into an additional `<activity android:name=".Splash">`

So the final code would look like:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity">
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Splash">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

    </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `<intent-filter>` from the MainActivity if you want the SplashActivity to be the entry point of your application.

> Splash screen activity does not showing

You have two icons for your app in the launcher at the moment. You need to open the SplashActivity instead of the MainActivity

Comment: removed <intent-filter> ...no use ...default activity not found

Comment: In the comment you posted in the other answer, seems you also deleted the MAIN intent filter. Don't do that. You need at least one of those

Answer (score 0):

Your main activity manifest entry should like:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"/>
```

Comment: It says that ...default activity not found

Comment: Add the following to you splash screen activity intent filter: ```<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />```

Comment: I added this line but it again says "default activity not found "

Comment: Please post what you have

Comment: I have three activity -> splash screen activity,main activity and a signup activity.

Comment: <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".SplashScreen" >
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".SignUpActivity" />
    </application>

Answer (score -1):

You have written this chunk of code two times.
You can just remove it from the MainActivity part. It worked out for me.

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```